# Where C++ calls destructors?

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, destructor

Assuming `Member` and `MyList` are two user defined classes. In the following code:

```
void fillList(MyList &list1)
{
    Member m1("aaa");
    Member m2("bbb");
    list1.insert(m1);
    list1.insert(m2);   
}

void func1()
{
    MyList lst;
    fillList(lst);
    lst.printAll();
}

int main()
{
    func1();
    return 0;
}
```

At which point does C++ call destructor of each `m1`, `m2` and `lst`?

Is it always safe to assume C++ does not remove an object which will be used again?

Comment: Why not run it? This seems like something that would be trivial to verify with a couple of print statements.

Comment: `Is it always safe to assume C++ does not remove an object which will be used again?` No. But if this case works depends on your insert method.

Comment: @Quirliom Seriously? SO has so many questions of "UB which works"..

Comment: @deviantfan Actually I need to know it for designing `insert` :)

Comment: @sermin As said in the comments below, if insert takes no reference (`void insert(Member m)` but not `void insert(Member &m)`) then it´s ok, because the value is copied when passing. When `m1` and `m2` get removed, the inserted copy stays somewhere in the list. If you refer to the deleted object with references and pointers because `insert` didn´t copy it, then it´s bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *At which point does C++ call destructor of each m1, m2 and lst?*

The destructors are called at the end of the scope, in the reverse order of the objects definitions. In your case, `func1()` is first called, which defines `lst`, then calls `fillList()`, which defines `m1` and `m2`. Next `fillList()` ends, so now `m2` then `m1` destructors are called (in reverse order of their declaration). Finally `func1()` ends, so `lst` destructor is called.

> *Is it always safe to assume C++ does not remove an object which will be used again?*

I don't really understand what you mean. A destructed object is gone, you cannot use it anymore. Trying to access it (via a dangling pointer/reference) is just undefined behaviour.

Comment: Does it mean `printAll` would infringe memory of m1 and m2 which are destroyed by now?

Comment: @sermin Does `insert()` take references, and nowhere inside copies are created? Then it´s a problem.

Comment: @sermin If `insert` copies the objects, then everything is fine. If it instead uses references, then you end up with dangling references, and that's bad. But most `insert` functions are actually copying. In your case it better copy, otherwise you're in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Destructors are called at the end of their scope (if allocated on the 'stack') or when you manually call their `delete` operator (if allocated dynamically).

As to your other question, it is most definitely *not* safe to assume anything of the kind. C++ gladly lets you cut off your own legs with as blunt a saw as you like. It might ask you if you'd like some kitty shaped bandaids (that you have to make yourself) during it, but that's about it.

Comment: That last part is going to be my new Skype away-message.

Comment: Almost mentioned putting the bandaids on the high shelf for you, but I figured it was getting a bit dark.